# Inputmask is not removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, input-mask

Please tell me, inputmask is not deleted.
What could be the problem?
The code has a condition if the country code from the array is equal to the value of input and the key with the code 8 is pressed, then the imputmask plugin is removed from the input. This is not happening now, because different country code values ​​and input values ​​in the script. In the input itself, you can see that the values ​​are the same.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#phone").inputmask("+380 (99) 999-99-99");
})
var phones = [{
    "country": "UA",
    "code": "+380",
    "mask": "(99) 999-99-99"
  },
  {
    "country": "RU",
    "code": "+7",
    "mask": "(999) 999-99-99"
  },
  {
    "country": "MD",
    "code": "+373",
    "mask": "(99) 999-99-99"
  }
];
var find_phone = 0;
$("#phone").keydown(function(event) {
  var val = $(this).val();
  val = val.replace(/[^+\d]/g, '');

  var phone_arr = phones.find(phones => val.includes(phones.code));
  if (phone_arr != null && find_phone == 0) {
    find_phone = 1;
    $(this).inputmask(phone_arr.code + " " + phone_arr.mask);
  }
  if (phone_arr != null) {
    console.log(phone_arr.code);
    console.log(val);
  }
  else {}
  if (phone_arr != null && phone_arr.code == val && event.which == 8) {

    find_phone = 0;
    $(this).inputmask('remove');
    $(this).val("");

  } else {}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/inputmask/4.0.9/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="phone" value="+380123456789">
```

Answer (score 0):

`inputmask` accepts multiple masks

https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask#keepstatic

```js
var phones = [{
    "country": "UA",
    "code": "+380",
    "mask": "(99) 999-99-99"
  },
  {
    "country": "RU",
    "code": "+7",
    "mask": "(999) 999-99-99"
  },
  {
    "country": "MD",
    "code": "+373",
    "mask": "(99) 999-99-99"
  }
];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#phone").inputmask({
    mask: phones.map(phone => phone.code  + ' ' + phone.mask)
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/inputmask/4.0.9/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="phone" value="+380123456789">
```

Comment: You may have noticed that you cannot change the mask.

Comment: @Vector No. Try clearing the input and type +7

Comment: While it doesn't work well, it doesn't always remove code immediately.